# Adding entity expansion before soap envelope in java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to code java program for the below example. I am not able to find the way to add Doctype before the soap envelope.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE order SYSTEM "c:\order.dtd">
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/order">

<order>
<cust_id>1</cust_id>
<cust_name>Bob Smith</cust_name>
<creditcardnum>999999999999</creditcardnum>
<creditcardexpiry>0609</creditcardexpiry>
<item>
<prod_id>1</prod_id>
<quantity>2</quantity>
</item>
</order>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes ... what?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you shouldn't be adding a DOCTYPE to your SOAP messages, even if you somehow get it to work.

The slightly longer answer is that according to the specs for SOAP, a SOAP message MUST NOT contain a DTD.  There are most likely a few reasons for this but there are definite concerns allowing DTD's as it opens the door for malicious attacks such as XXE (XML External Entity Attacks).

Here are some additional resources:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing